# React Testing Library user-event throws error `TypeError: root.elementFromPoint is not a function`

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing, user-input, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a test which writes a / in an editor and observes a menu appearing.
For this I try to use the userEvent.type() method that simulates real keyboard typing events. However, I get the error  `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: root.elementFromPoint is not a function]`(see full error on bottom)

I have tried a few things, and I've included the (not-working) test below:

- userEvent.hover() doesn't throw any error but also doesn't cause the expected change in the dom tree
- userEvent.click() gives the same error as userEvent.type()
- the tree seems to change if I wait for a bit, but the changed tree also doesn't contain the expected html elements
- I've used "textbox" instead of "editor" as an aria role and I still get the issue

The RichTextRenderer is a react component that uses TipTap (based on Prosemirror) to create blocks of editable text. The thing is, I'd understand type() not to work maybe because it's a content-editable div. However, click() also doesn't work which totally doesn't make sense. And when I google elementFromPoint it's a function, so the error is also weird. How can I get userEvent.type() to work and actually change the content of the paragraph with role "editor"?

I have written the following test:

```
test("Typing slash opens the slash menu", async () => {
  render(
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <RichTextRenderer/>
    </DndProvider>
  );
  const block = screen.getByRole("editor");
  screen.debug();
  expect(block).toBeInTheDocument();
  userEvent.type(block, "/");
}, 10000);
```

and screen.debug() prints the following tree:

```
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div
              aria-expanded="false"
              class="ProseMirror editor"
              contenteditable="true"
              tabindex="0"
            >
              <p
                class="is-empty is-editor-empty"
                data-placeholder=""
                role="editor"
              >
                <br />
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

the full error given is:

```
 console.error
    Error: Uncaught [TypeError: root.elementFromPoint is not a function]
        at reportException (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
        at invokeEventListeners (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLParagraphElementImpl._dispatch (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
        at HTMLParagraphElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
        at HTMLParagraphElement.dispatchEvent (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
        at /home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:25:20
        at /home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:66:16
        at batchedUpdates$1 (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22380:12)
        at act (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1042:14) TypeError: root.elementFromPoint is not a function
        at posAtCoords (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/prosemirror-view/src/domcoords.js:245:18)
        at EditorView.posAtCoords$1 [as posAtCoords] (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/prosemirror-view/src/index.js:275:12)
        at Object.<anonymous>.handlers.mousedown (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/prosemirror-view/src/input.js:266:18)
        at HTMLDivElement.view.dom.addEventListener.view.eventHandlers.<computed> (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/prosemirror-view/src/input.js:46:9)
        at HTMLDivElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
        at invokeEventListeners (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLParagraphElementImpl._dispatch (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
        at HTMLParagraphElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
        at HTMLParagraphElement.dispatchEvent (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
        at /home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:25:20
        at /home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:66:16
        at batchedUpdates$1 (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22380:12)
        at act (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1042:14)
        at Object.eventWrapper (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:65:28)
        at fireEvent (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:16:35)
        at Function.fireEvent.<computed> [as mouseDown] (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:125:36)
        at clickElement (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:72:52)
        at click (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:136:7)
        at typeImpl (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/type.js:172:36)
        at Object.type (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/type.js:155:14)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/src/documentRenderers/richtext/test/slashMenu.test.tsx:39:13)
        at _callCircusTest (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:212:5)
        at _runTest (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:149:3)
        at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:63:9)
        at run (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:25:3)
        at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:176:21)
        at jestAdapter (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:109:19)
        at runTestInternal (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:380:16)
        at runTest (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:472:34)
        at Object.worker (/home/nikko/Folders/Uni/SoftwareProject/typecell-next/node_modules/jest-runner/build/testWorker.js:133:12)

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at reportException (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:70:28)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLParagraphElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLParagraphElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
```

Comment: You're trying to type into a `<p>` tag - you should use [`userEvent.type`](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/#typeelement-text-options) on `<input>` or `<textarea>` elements.

Comment: So is there something else I could use for <div contenteditable="true">?

Comment: @Nikko Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Comment: It was more than a year ago, so unfortunately I don't remember anymore :/ I think I switched to another testing library

Answer (score 1):

The testing library is most likely based on `jsdom`, which doesn't implement layouting. At the same time, Prosemirror (and therefore TipTap) uses the layout information.

For *my* tests, it was enough to stub layouting functions.

```
function getBoundingClientRect(): DOMRect {
  const rec = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    height: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 0,
  };
  return { ...rec, toJSON: () => rec };
}

class FakeDOMRectList extends Array<DOMRect> implements DOMRectList {
  item(index: number): DOMRect | null {
    return this[index];
  }
}

document.elementFromPoint = (): null => null;
HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = getBoundingClientRect;
HTMLElement.prototype.getClientRects = (): DOMRectList =>
  new FakeDOMRectList();
Range.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = getBoundingClientRect;
Range.prototype.getClientRects = (): DOMRectList =>
  new FakeDOMRectList();
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to mock document.elementFromPoint.
add document.elementFromPoint = () => {} before describe().